# Gracefully Shutdown TLS connection in C OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I just create a TLS connection and then immediately close it. For now this is my shutdown function:

```
// Close SSL and socket.
// SSL_shutdown will return 1 if the shutdown process has completed.
// SSL_shutdown sends a close_notify to the server, a completed shutdown means we recieved the close_notify back from our peer.
// Not necessary to wait for the close_notify from peer.
void clean_up(SSL *ssl, int *sockfd)
{
    // We send a close_notify and close the socket.
    // It is not necessary to wait for the servre's close_notify.
    int ret;
    do
    {
        ret = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            // does nothing for now
            SSL_get_error(ssl, ret);
            ret = 0;
        };
    } while (ret < 0);
    SSL_free(ssl); // Frees up the allocated memory.
    close(*sockfd);
}
```

This always results in TCP RST packets being sent. In the picture below my PC sends it first, sometimes its the server... Is this normal is there a better way to do shutdown. I tried with other functions with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL_shutdown just initiates the shutdown of the TLS session. It is expected that one is waiting for the peer to also shutdown the TLS session. If one does not wait for this then the SSL shutdown alert from the peer will be received but the socket is closed before reading it from the socket buffer - resulting in a TCP RST.

To cite from [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_shutdown.html):

> The shutdown process will then be considered completed **once the peer responds in turn with a close_notify shutdown alert message**... the preferred method of waiting for the shutdown to complete is to use SSL_read(3) until SSL_get_error(3) indicates EOF by returning SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN

Comment: Hey thanks, I am not sure if the manpage is a bit outdated because SSL_get_error will return SSL_ERROR_SSL becuase SSL_read couldnt read so its an SSL ERROR. But using ERR_get_error and ERR_GET_REASON I get the actual reason SSL_R_UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING. 


So I just used SSL_READ with ERR_GET_REASON(ERR_get_error()) and I get SSL_R_UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING.

Now it works as it should.